# Javascript is done, but browser do not reflect these changes (ASYNC?)

Tags: javascript, c#, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

I am using CEF and CefSharp. 
I have one c# class that its purpose is to know if JS function call is done and then call call JS again on curent element xPath in

```
class test {
   //array of Xpaths of elements
   elementsXpaths 
   public IsDone(){
       LoadNext()
   }
   LoadNext(){
       call = string.Format("click('{0}')", elemenentsXpath[next])
       browser.ExecuteScriptAsync(call)
   }
}
```

Then  JS something like this

```
function click(xpath){
   elementFoundedByXPath.click()
   elementFoundedByXPath.style.backgroundColor = "#FF0000"
   test.isDone();
}
```

My problem is, that background color is not changed right after click(). 
So for example I have one element, clicking on this element reveal some other elements (fe I click on show login button and login and password input are shown after this click) and then click do not fails, but I cant see that login and password input. Very odd. I would guess that this will fail, because element is not founded (I am checking this in JS).

I am also checking this in debug, when I have breakpoint on LoadNext I can see that LoadNext is called and backgroundColor of previous element is not changed.

I assumed that if I do click on that element I can be sure that actual click was performed.

Is this problem with async calling of JS? Will EvaluateScriptAsync() help me ? In that case somebody show me some easy example and difference between these two functions ? Or is problem most likely somewhere else ?

Comment: What version are you using? How are you registering your `test` object?

Comment: `test` is initialized in contstructor of user control `public BrowserTabUserControl(ChromiumWebBrowser browser)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            browser.Load(Variables.defaultURL);
            browserPanel.Controls.Add(browser);
            this.InitilializePlaybackRecordObjects(browser);
            this.RegisterCSharpClasses(browser);
            this.browser = browser;
        }`

`InitilializePlaybackRecord` create instance of test object and `RegisterCSharpClasses(browser)` register them using `RegisterJSObject` 

Version of CefSharp.WinForms is 41.0.1.0
@amaitland

Comment: Are you able to upgrade to the latest version? There's an `RegisterAsyncJsObject` that might be useful. What I think is happening is that you've got the renderer process in effectively a tight loop, the `RegisterJsObject` calls actually block the render process, so at no point does it actually get a chance to update the `UI`. That's just my theory.

Comment: I tried to update, but now my instance of IWinFormsWebBrowser do not have method ExecuteScriptAsync or even EvaluateScriptAsync. I do not see anything special about this in changelog of 43, so why it disappeared?   @amaitland

Comment: They were made into extension methods on the `IWebBrowser` interface for which `IWinFormsWebBrowser` inherits, so you should have no problems using them. https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/43/CefSharp/WebBrowserExtensions.cs#L189 Before you could only execute scripts on the main frame, now you can pick a specific frame. So overall there's a lot more flexibility.

Comment: Where for example is browser.reload() and browser.Title now placed ? If you can point me to more detailed changelog this will be really nice. @amaitland

Comment: Same `WebBrowserExtensions` file. For the most part you shouldn't have to do anything for those methods. VS should just continue along happily. The migration document is https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/CefSharp-43